# Express bodyParser

Tags: node.js, express

I have a big problem with Node.js and Express.

I want to use the body elements of my request but I dont know how to use the `bodyParser()` in my program; it's not just `app.use()`...

See for yourself:

```
requestServer = function(){
  var express = require('express');
  this.ex = express;

  //this.app = require('express')();
  this.app = express();
  this.server = require('http').createServer(this.app);
  this.io = require('socket.io').listen(this.server, {log: false});
  this.socket = []; 

  this.app.post('/test/', this.testFunction.bind(this));

  this.io.sockets.on('connection', this.socketConnection.bind(this));

  this.app.use(express.bodyParser());
};

...

requestServer.prototype.positionChange = function(req, res){    
  console.log(req.body); // says its undefined???
  console.log(req.body.name); // also undefined :(
};

...

var server = new requestServer();
server.listen(6667);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: where is `positionChange` called?

Comment: is there any reason you use `this` ? a little bit unconventional.

Comment: Have you tried to move `app.use(express.bodyParser());` before you start listening to connections?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use nodejs, express and bodyParser i suggest you to make yourself clear about the method used for the request. Do you mean to use the get method or the post ? Remember to answer according to the utilization of the information you gain with the communication.

I suppose you want to use the **post** method because the [body parser](http://expressjs.com/api.html#req.body) has been created for the post method, and the [query](http://expressjs.com/api.html#req.query) for the **get** method.

---client side: just write a form element specifying it uses the post method. Give each input element a name.

```
 <form method="POST" action="/readRequest">
      <input type="text" name="email" hint="email" value="" size="40"/>
      <inpnut type="submit" value="request" /> 
 </form>
```

---node side :
into the middleware you want to catch the */readRequest*, read the values with the '.' operator on the request element

```
function (req, res, next){ 
  console.log('Email received: '+req.body.email); 
  next();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

BodyParser is no longer being used widely due to security exploits with it. It is now integrated in Express itself. Don't use it.

Answer (score 0):

Should not this

```
var server = new requestServer();
server.listen(6667);
```

be this

```
var server = new requestServer();
server.app.listen(6667);
```

Since app is the express object, which is returned. Can you post the full code where `positionChange` is called.